# What happens after anger disappears?

Tags: vipassana, meditation-practicalities

I practiced meditation few years ago,had reached a state where experience consepte of "I"was an illusion.when was Illusion  of the I disappeared anger disappeared altogether. But  I can't  meditate now.It is totally  different. Now wondering thoughts are less.what shall I do ?

Comment: I did vipassana meditation. Sometimes I felt iam not attracted to the thoughts which was coming to the mind. Once I thought it was the bavanga citta.

Comment: my two cents is that one time during what i would consider "meditation" i observed anger and later wondered if it would ceae altogether. but it didn't: i often get angry still

Answer (score 1):

If you can give more details on the type of meditation and your current situation -- like anger, and whether 'I' is still there or not -- helpers here might reach you.

Assuming that you are doing sensation-Vipassana, anger and 'I' have a comeback. As you mentioned, "less wondering thoughts" means that now you are able to see thoughts too.

It's a progress in meditation -- things coming and passing by, and you are aware of them. Your main focus must be to alter the defiled behaviour pattern by accepting the sensations and  thoughts as they are, and maintaining noble silence in front of them (this part of maintaining noble••• comes under practice of *Citta-Vipassana*).

**What comes after anger?**

Anger generates heat in body. Heat is due to sankharas. After anger seems to pass-by, leftover sankharas induce (or to be precise, divert mind to) other defiled characteristics like lust, memory-loss, frustration etc. These defilements, if  remain unseen wisely, enables anger to have a comeback.

Answer (score 0):

> ``"Now, O bhikkhus, I say to you that these teachings of which I have direct knowledge and which I have made known to you — these you should thoroughly learn, cultivate, develop, and frequently practice, that the life of purity may be established and may long endure, for the welfare and happiness of the multitude, out of compassion for the world, for the benefit, well being, and happiness of gods and men.
>   "And what, bhikkhus, are these teachings? They are the four foundations of mindfulness, the four right efforts, the four constituents of psychic power, the five faculties, the five powers, the seven factors of enlightenment, and the Noble Eightfold Path. These, bhikkhus, are the teachings of which I have direct knowledge, which I have made known to you, and which you should thoroughly learn, cultivate, develop, and frequently practice...." -DN16

The training doesn't change. The only peculiar part is when one has had the entering into a cessation attainment, emerging from that there is a dilemma as to whether one should practice that absorbtion as fruition re-attainment by making specific determinations or to keep training as before.